# What is the standard font and size for iPhone navigation title?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts

Could anybody tell me please, what is the standard font and size for iPhone development?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Helvetica Bold, size 20.

To obtain it you can use this convenience method in case Apple ever decides to change the font face:

```
UIFont *navigationTitleFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very fast answer!

Comment: I know this was a rather old question (three years!) but may I ask whether you just found the font through trial and error or it was in some official documentation? Basically, how did you find it out?

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple documents,

> Text in a navigation controller uses the same font size that body style text uses for the large setting (specifically, 17 points).

So, I think is System (Helvetica Neue) Bold 17.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ColorImagesText.html